# What will be the summation formula for harmonic number with extra parameter?

Tags: calculus, summation, partial-fractions

```
sum = n/1 + n/2 + ... ... ... + n/i
```

What is the formula that could be used to calculate `sum`?

Comment: Harmonic sum does not have a general formula

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example
$$n\left(\ln{n}+\gamma+\frac{1}{2n}-\sum_{i=1}^{+\infty}\frac{B_{2i}}{2in^{2i}}\right),$$
where $B_{2i}$ they are Bernoulli numbers.